# access local file within Heroku console for one time seed import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, heroku

I'm seeding a production database from a CSV export.  I have the CSV and the method to import the data, but I don't want to commit the CSV to the repo, I'd like to be able to run the importer from Heroku console, but I don't seem to be able to access the document.

**When I do this on local console:**

```
csv_path = "/Users/{{my_user}}/{{parent_folder}}/{{my_app}}/lib/csvs/{{seed_csv}}.csv"
Importers::Csv::MyModel.new.import(csv_path)
```

**It works as expected**

When I run it on Heroku console. (heroku run rails c etc...) I get this **error**:

```
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/{{my_user}}/{{parent_folder}}/{{my_app}}/lib/csvs/{{seed_csv}}.csv")
```

How can I import this file to my method without committing it to the repo?

Comment: This post is fitting to your question: https://joey.io/how-to-securely-move-or-transfer-files-to-heroku. However, I would solve your problem by connecting directly to remote database from your machine.

Comment: @PetrGazarov. are you saying use the production heroku database configs as my local configs and seed the data running the app on my local machine?

Comment: yes, you can find the database connection credentials in Heroku environment variables.

Comment: Thanks, had to check because yours is of course the simpler solution and it seemed almost too simple to be true.  Kicking myself now. Thanks!